# DataGridTextColumn displays NaN when button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that displays a list of different oil names, percentage of their usage, drop count and add/subtract drop buttons per row.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say the names are Pennziol, Castrol and Valvoline. Their initial percentage usage value (suppose to be float) and drop count (int) are 0. if the "+" button for a row is clicked, the drop count will increment. If Pennziol is then incremented by 1, its percentage usage will become 100% with the other remaining 0%. If Castrol is then clicked twice, its percentage will be 66.6% and Pennziol will be reduced to 33.3% with Valvoline remaining 0%.

My code is suppose to be doing this updating the data every time a button is clicked, but it returns the value in all **`Formula %`** column cells as **`NaN`**.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private OilList mOilList = new OilList();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add Oils to Oil Grid Table
        foreach (Oil oil in mOilList.Oils)
        {
            OilGridXaml.Items.Add(oil);        
        }          
    }


    private void Button_Click_Increment(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
        Oil oil = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Oil;
        oil.AddDrop();

        mOilList.UpdateFormulaWeight();

        PerfumeGridXaml.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

**Oil.cs**

```
public void AddDrop()
    {
        mDropCount++;
        mOilAmount = mDropSize * mDropCount;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DropCount");
    }

public float UsagePercentage
    {
        get { return mUsagePercentage; }
        set
        {
            if (mUsagePercentage != value)
            { 
                mUsagePercentage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UsagePercentage");
            }
        }
    }
```

**OilList.cs**

```
public void UpdateFormulaWeight()
    {
        foreach (Oil oil in mOils)
            mFormulaTotalWeight += oil.TotalWeight;

        foreach (Oil oil in mOils)
        {
            oil.UsagePercentage = (oil.TotalWeight / mFormulaTotalWeight) * 100f;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UsagePercentage");
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:name="OilGridXaml" ... ItemsSource="{Binding}">...
<!-- USAGE PERCENTAGE -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Formula %" Foreground="LightGray" Binding="{Binding UsagePercentage, StringFormat={}{0:F2}%}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="64">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>

<!-- DROP COUNT -->
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Cell_Drop_Count" Header="Drop Count" Foreground="LightGray" Binding="{Binding DropCount}" Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**UPDATE**

`Oil` and `OilList` inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged` with same effect

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

Comment: Check Kunal suggestion then (datatypes and division by 0). By the way, the fact that it doesn't work with 'NotifyPropertychanged', doesn't mean that it was not required...

Comment: One drop equals 0.01. Plus my formula is correct, because the percentage value for one drop is (.01 / .01) * 100 = 100(%) and the datatype is `float`.

Comment: @P.Manthe I don't know what's causing the problem, so I created a separate project with minimal functionality and the columns update with the correct percentages. But in the beginning, I didn't have INotifyPropertyChanged. So If I did this after your answer, your answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `PropertyChanged` event fired in your `UsagePercentage`. I think the value of your property will change properly, but the `DataGrid` won't update then. So it stays to its initial value which seemed to be `NaN`.

The `PerfumeGridXaml.Items.Refresh()` will only recreate the view, but not refresh the `ItemsSource` nor any of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your code if the result of (oil.TotalWeight / mFormulaTotalWeight) this division is 0, then you will get the NaN value as an output as per the below mentioned line of code.

```
oil.UsagePercentage = (oil.TotalWeight / mFormulaTotalWeight) * 100f;
```

Also check whether the datatypes are floating/double of the Variables/Properties involved.

Comment: One click returns a whole number of 100% and the datatype is `float`.